# How to group data?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, lodash

**How to write a script that groups the elements of an array into an array of arrays (or object of arrays), where the last is an array of elements grouped by sequence.**

**If next element Id is a part of sequence, it falls into prev group, else will be created new array and element will fall into it.**

**If element Id is higher than Id of prev element more than 1 - is is the same sequence = current array.**

**If element Id is higher than Id of prev element more than 2 - is is the next sequence = next (new) array.**

**If element neighbors Ids from all sides are both more than current Id - current element will create an array containing itself and it key will be its own Id.**

**Its no matter will be result is an array or an object - generating keys is easy, but group elements is hard to me now.**

**You can try writing in JavaScript, you can even use the Lodash library.**

```
const data = [
{id: 1},
{id: 2},
{id: 3},
{id: 7},
{id: 9},
{id: 10},
{id: 12},
{id: 14},
{id: 15},
{id: 16}];
```

==========================================

```
const result = [
0/"1-4": [
    {id: 1},
    {id: 2},
    {id: 3},
    {id: 4}],
1/"7": [
    {id: 7}],
2/"9-10": [
    {id: 9},
    {id: 10}],
3/"12": [
    {id: 12}],
4/"14-16": [
    {id: 14},
    {id: 15},
    {id: 16}]];
```

Comment: Is this for Homework?

Comment: no - it is a part of big work task, where i generate a lot of different data and then push it to the lib excelJs to generate xlsx file (report). all done but this moment is hard to me. simple _.groupBy() even with combined key for grouping i  think is helpless.

Answer (score 1):

You could use reduce to create an array of arrays where the next expected number is current item id plus one.

```js
const data = [
  {id: 1},
  {id: 2},
  {id: 3},
  {id: 7},
  {id: 9},
  {id: 10},
  {id: 12},
  {id: 14},
  {id: 15},
  {id: 16}]
.sort((a,b)=>a.id-b.id)//make sure it is sorted by id
.reduce(
  ([result,nextNum],item)=>{//nextNum is the next expected number
    if(nextNum===undefined){//first time nextNum is undefined
      nextNum=item.id;//set nextNum to id of current item
      result.push([]);//add empty array
    }
    if(!(nextNum===item.id)){//current item id is not the expected next number
      result.push([]);//add empty array
    }
    result[result.length-1].push(item);//add item to last array of the array of arrays
    return [result,item.id+1];//next expected number is current item id + 1
  },
  [[],undefined]//initial values for result and nextNum
);
console.log(data)
```

Comment: wow! amazing. thanks. i will carefully look the logic of your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use chained [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) calls to create the required structure:

```js
const data = [{"id":1},{"id":2},{"id":3},{"id":7},{"id":9},{"id":10},{"id":12},{"id":14},{"id":15},{"id":16}];

const arrayOfGroups = data
  .reduce((r, o, i) => {
    // if first or not sequence add new sub array
    if(!r.length || o.id !== data[i - 1].id + 1) r.push([]);
    
    // push to last sub array
    r[r.length - 1].push(o);
    
    return r;
  }, []);
  
const objectOfGroups = arrayOfGroups.reduce((r, a, i) => {
    const start = a[0].id;
    const end = a[a.length - 1].id;
    // if start and end are equal, add just start (to main the order of insertion, start can be just a number)
    const key = start === end ? 
      `${i}/${start}` : `${i}/${start}-${end}`;
    
    r[key] = a;
  
    return r;
  }, {});
  
console.log('arrayOfGroups', arrayOfGroups);

console.log('objectOfGroups', objectOfGroups);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a single loop approach by checking the last array of the result set and check the last object's `id` if it is in wanted range.

If not, then add a new empty array to the result set. Later push the actual object to the last array.

```js
var data = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }, { id: 7 }, { id: 9 }, { id: 10 }, { id: 12 }, { id: 14 }, { id: 15 }, { id: 16 }],
    grouped = data.reduce((r, o) => {
        var last = r[r.length - 1];
        if (!last || last[last.length - 1].id + 1 !== o.id) {
            r.push(last = []);
        }
        last.push(o);
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(grouped);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```